# Cambiar color HEADERS QtreeWidget Pyside

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Como se podría cambiar el color (background) del header del QTreeWidget con PySide ?
"QHeaderView" no me ha funcionado, alguna idea

```
self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("QTreeWidget{"
                                       "border: inset;"
                                       "background-color:#272727;}")
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la documentación de [hojas de estilo para PyQt](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview)
para personalizar un QHeaderView debes editar la hoja de estilo del siguiente modo:

```
self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section {"
                                       "border: inset;"
                                       "background-color:#272727;}")
```

Lo he probado en el siguiente ejemplo y funciona.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.test_model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.test_model)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section {"
                                       "border: inset;"
                                       "background-color:#272727;}")
w = Widget()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```